# Fabrication has_many though with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, has-many-through, fabrication-gem

I'm just getting into testing and I have many models that utilize a has_many though relationship. In each case, one model requires that the other be present at the time of save. I've run into a wall with every testing system I've tried (FactoryGirl, Fixtures, and now Fabrication) where I can not figure out how to set up the tests correctly to replicate this behavior.

I [followed this GIST as an example](https://gist.github.com/1077311/83c1540c8cfde3360523fbeb5bc2a6c2e1b89edf) but changed the `after_build` to `before_save` as the models are requiring the "though" model at that time. Am I approaching this the wrong way? How does one test this relationship/functionality?

[I've created a GIST that is hopefully easier to use/read.](https://gist.github.com/eric-norcross/7346423)

Answer (score 3):

I changed this

```
Fabricator(:brand) do
  title "Coca Cola"

  before_save do |brand|
    styles Fabricate(:brand_style, :brand => brand, :style => Fabricate(:style))
  end
end
```

to this

```
Fabricator(:brand) do
  title "Coca Cola"

  styles(count: 3) { Fabricate(:style) }
end
```

and now the test is passing. However, I'm not sure if this is the correct way of setting this up, so if anyone has any additional insight it would be appreciated.